# GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation -- when using Intervention Image

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

Controller File:

```
use Image;

if ($request->file('dp')) {
        $image = $request->file('dp');
        $img_name = hexdec(uniqid('', true)).'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Image::make($image)->resize(150,150)->save('upload/employee_Img/'.$img_name);
        $image_path = 'upload/employee_Img/'.$img_name;
    }

Employees::insert([
        'dp' => $image_path,
        'created_at' => Carbon::now()
    ]);
```

It was returning an error saying -- GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to XAMPP control panel. Then press the **config** button on beside apache start button. From there go to **php.ini** file.
Then search for **gd** or **gd2** and remove the quatation before the following line - ;**extension=gd -> extension=gd**.

Restart the apache and mysql server and you're good to go.

[[image: find the php.ini file here][1]]

Comment: in my php.ini "extension=gd2" was already uncommented, also i see via "phpinfo()" that gd2 is enabled, still i get this warning 
"GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation"